# Connected to ssh session via my browser. How can I access my local files through the browser?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, ipython

I'm connected to a VM on a private network at address 'abc.def.com' using `ssh`, and on that VM there's an application that hosts a Python web app (IPython Notebook) that I can access by pointing my local browser to 'abc.def.com:7777'.

From that web app I can call shell commands by preceding them with '!', for example `!ls -lt` will list the files in the VM current working directory.  But since I'm using my own laptop's browser, I think I should be able to run shell commands on my local files as well.  How would I do that?

If that's not possible, what Python/shell command can I run from within the web app to automatically get my laptop's IP address to use things like `scp`?  I know how to get my IP address, but I'd like to create a program that will automatically enable scp for whoever uses it.

Comment: You want to what? Create a web site/application (with python) that can be installed and will enable scp to the running host?

Comment: I want an IPython function "def upload('/path/from/local', '/path/on/remote')" that will upload a local file to a path on the remote server.

Comment: I don't know IPython Notebook or this application you are using but it is **extremely** unlikely (effectively impossible) for an application running on a server (even the local machine) from accessing your local files through the browser directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ssh access so you could *possibly* write a python function that would let you transfer files via `scp` the secure copy command which uses ssh to communicate. If you exchange keys with the server you wouldn't have to put in a password so I see no problem from that standpoint. The issue is if you have an address for your local machine to be accessed from the server.

I work on various remotes from my laptop all day and from my laptop to the sever I could have this function:

```
 def scp_to_server(address, local_file, remote_file):
      subprocess.call(['scp',local_file,"myusername@{}:{}".format(address, remote_file)])
```

that would copy a file from my local machine to the remote provided the paths were correct, I have permissions to copy the files, and my local machine's `id_rsa.pub` key is in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote.

I have no way to initiate a secure copy from the remote to my local machine however because I don't have an address to access the local machine from that I can "see" on the remote.

If I open the terminal on my laptop and run `hostname` I see `mylaptop.local` and on the remote I see `remoteserver@where.i.work.edu` but the first is a local address I can see it from other machines on my LAN at home, (because I have configured that) but I can't see `mylaptop.local` from the remote. I  know there is a way to configure that so I could find my laptop at home from anywhere, but I never had the need to do that (since I bring the laptop with me) so I can't help you there. I think there are a few more hurdels to go-over than you would like.

You could implement the function above on your local machine and transfer the files that way though.